# Enforce User-Defined Metadata x-amz-meta being set on AWS S3 via Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Is there anyway to enforce User-Defined Metadata i.e. `x-amz-meta` being set on an object being uploaded to an `AWS S3 bucket` - via a `bucket policy` or otherwise

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

Ctrl+F "User-Defined Metadata"

I know about Post Policies
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

and Condition Matching

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-ConditionMatching

But nothing seems to fit.

I want the `S3 bucket` to reject an object if it does not have
`x-amz-meta-my-value` set.

Answer (score 0):

If this were possible, it should be listed among the [Available Condition Keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#AvailableKeys-iamV2) for S3 policies.

Since it does not appear, it does not appear to be supported.

Note that the `s3:x-amz-metadata-directive` condition key shown in the documentation is not related to what you are looking for.  This only controls whether a `PUT/COPY` request is allowed/required to replace the metadata when copying an object or leave it as-is.